# VBA - Access - Different Queries for each Columns

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have 2 different columns as listed below ( each has 3 different fields )
[image]

`Column1` should query: `Query_day1` and `Column 2` should `execute:query_day2`.Both Queries are different. My problem is on which event I should run `Query_day1`. My following code  always returns results for `Query_day2`

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
 SQL = "Query_Day1"
 Form_frmNewForm.Form.RecordSource = SQL

 SQL = "Query_Day2"
 Form_frmNewForm.Form.RecordSource = SQL
```

End Sub

Comment: These look like they are the same data in these two columns? You can only have one record source for a form. There is no way to have more than one. You can have subforms. You can also set your record source to all the records then filter to the day.

Comment: @Brad Data is same but queries are different

Comment: @Brad filter by Query_Day1?

Comment: It looks like your queries are something like `select WorkorderID, Customer, ProblemDescription from SomeTable where Date = #Day1#` and `select WorkorderID, Customer, ProblemDescription from SomeTable where Date = #Day2#`. Can you set the record source to `select WorkorderID, Customer, ProblemDescription from SomeTable`  then filter by date on the form?

Comment: @Brad my query is WHERE [Service Order Labor].SERVICED= Date()

Comment: @Brad and Query 2 is WHERE [Service Order Labor].SERVICED= Date()+1

Comment: @brad Query 2 isWHERE [Service Order Labor].SERVICED= Date()+2